# JFace dialog always on top and modeless

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created a JFace Modeless Dialog and trying to set shell style with following options

```
setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE |SWT.MODELESS |SWT.ON_TOP);
```

I want this dialog to be always on top , but the dialog gets minimized when I minimize the eclipse workbench.

Am I missing something with the shell style bits or is this the expected behavior?

How can I make an always on top dialog even if we minimize the eclipse application?

```
public class Capture extends Dialog {

    public Capture(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE |SWT.MODELESS |SWT.ON_TOP);
    }

}
```

Comment: `SWT.OP_TOP` is the right flag to tell shells to always stay on top, even if the application is inactive, But it is a _hint_ and might be ignored by some windows systems. I just tried [with a modified SWT snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet50.java) and it works as expected on Win7.  Which window system do you use?

Comment: Win 7 only - But I am using Jface dialog whereas the snippet you mentioned is using SWT dialog. I have added the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `null` for the parent Shell so that the dialog is not a child of the window you are minimizing.

Comment: Thanks greg !! Can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432507/reuse-project-explorer-view-for-your-custom-plugin-project

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. So posting this as an answer.
What is the parentShell in this? That determines the life and behavior of the dialog. Either create a new shell or put null as the shell. That should remove the tie up with the workbench.
Another question : Why are trying this?